# Sleep() executed in "wrong" order.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

My problem is pretty straight forward:

```
        label1.Text = "Start";
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label1.Text = "Finish";
```

Why does Sleep() happen before the label changes to "Start"?

How can I change the label, then sleep, then change again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sleep happens in the correct spot, the problem is there is a 4th step you are missing. What really is happening is

```
    label1.Text = "Start";
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    label1.Text = "Finish";
    DrawUpdatedValuesOfLabel1OnTheUI();
```

The UI does not update until the execution returns to the "message loop", you need to return control to the message loop while you wait your two seconds so you get your updated UI.

If you are using .NET 4.5 the easiest way to do this is change you `Sleep` in to a `Delay` with async/await

```
public async Task YourFunction()
{
    label1.Text = "Start";
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    label1.Text = "Finish";
}
```

If you are not using .NET 4.5 the problem becomes a lot more complex to solve.

Comment: The question is tagged VS 2013, so I think it's safe to assume C# 5.0 is available.

Comment: @svick many people still target .NET 4.0, but if that is the case he could still use [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) and get async/await in .NET 4.0. However if he is using 3.5 or earlier he will need to use a very different solution ([Dai provides one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25318793/80274) (but it is not the best one))

Comment: I edited your answer with an alternate approach that works with .NET 4.0.  The code was taken from a WPF project, but the same concept can be applied to just about any windowing platform.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer And [your suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5544973) was rejected. You might want to post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No worries.  I appreciate you letting me know.  I'll post it as a separate answer as you suggested.